# What is funny about Frankie's line about aspiration?

Tags: plot-explanation, frankie-and-johnny

In *Frankie and Johnny*, Frankie says:

> **Aspiration? Have you been shaving again?**

What's funny about this line?

Comment: I haven't seen it but: Aspiration means two different things. "Hope or ambition of achieving something" and "To breathe".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Earlier, in the kitchen discussing "empathy", Johnny said, "You see, every day when I'm shaving, I look up a new word."

This is a reference back to that scene. The joke is that "Have you been shaving again?" was a substitute for "Are you using the word 'aspiration' / having 'aspirations' because you just looked it up in a dictionary?" and the implications of that. The remark was meant to be facetious.